# How to implement cross domain post with Chrome extension content script?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, post, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a Chrome extension which detects product pages on major online shopping websites, using id's and places a button on the page. The button is supposed to send AJAX data to a php script so as to store product information the content scripts took from the page. But since cross domain post is not allowed, how can I send information to a php script (for storing in a MySQL DB) from the extension?

Comment: can you use a hidden form submit?

Answer (score 0):

Why you think cross domain isnt allowed?
See the official docs about the manifest. A section there specifies the urls you can post/get cross-domain

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. It is possible to do cross domain get/post calls. You have to first set permissions for that domain though.